# MongoError: E11000 when trying to update a user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling, mongoose-schema

So I have a node app where users can register an account (username, email, pw, icon image) to use the site. I created a profile page with a link to an Edit Form to edit/update your username, email, and icon image. However, whenever I try to update a user's info, I get a MongoError.

This doesn't happen consistently. Sometimes it successfully updates, so I don't know what is causing the issue.

Here is the github link to my code: https://github.com/P4sc4l94/yelp-camp

My User schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

My User controller that is trying to update info:

```
module.exports.editProfile = async (req, res, next) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  const {username} = req.body.user;
  const {email} = req.body.user;
  const {image} = req.body.user
  console.log(id)
  console.log(username)
  console.log(email)
  console.log(image)
  const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(id, {username, email, image}, {
    new: true
  });
  user.save();

  console.log(user);
  req.logout();
  req.flash('success', 'Successfully updated profile!')
  return res.redirect(`/login`);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E11000 is a "duplicate key error" meaning that you cannot do "new" on the record, you could use `new` and `upsert` if you were querying for something other than the `id`

you should be doing `await user.save()` when its used, but there is no reason to be doing it here

you should also be casting your `id` as a document ID if you are using mongodb ID's, which i presume you are as a safety precaution

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Types
const { id } = req.params
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectId(id) }, { username, email, image });
```

Comment: Firstly, this worked, so thank you for that because I have been stumped for days! Second, why does this work? I have another model for creating camp profiles, and it also has an edit form so you can update the camp info. But I didn't have to do all of this to get that to work.

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate` is in itself a command to save the document, you would only need to use `save` if you where searching for a document first, then making updates, then finally saving. `await user.save()` will return the saved version on the database, if you use timestamps the timestamps will update after calling save. The reason you are getting the error though is entirely different. The database already has a document with the ID you were calling, when you were passing `{ new: true }` you were essentially telling the database to create it, and its getting a conflict, because ID is an index

Comment: any field that is an index has to be unique on the collection (table)

Comment: I thought the {new: true} was the issue, but I was told findOneAndUpdate will return the old version unless I set new:true and then save(). I was having the error even before that, but maybe it's because I needed to set 'id' as a document ID like you said.